# Why does MapReduce return _id and value parameters?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I need to make a map reduce function which will search for a certain set of conditions within a document and then if they are met, return the entire document (or make a new table with the documents which match).  The following is a simplified example of what i need to do but keep in mind that the actual documents have more to them.

Lets say i have two documents:

Document #1:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("542ec1a91d40cafd58b928b4"),
  "billing": {
    "category1": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email",
        "email": {
          "0": "test@what.com" 
        } 
      } 
    },
    "category2": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email",
        "email": {
          "0": "who@cares.net" 
        } 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Document #2:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("542ec1a91d40cafd58b928b4"),
  "billing": {
    "category1": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email",
        "email": {
          "0": "test@what.com" 
        } 
      } 
    },
    "category2": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email"
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I need to determine which documents have elements with a mode value of "email" but do not have a corresponding email element.  This is what i've got so far:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
  for(var bKey in this.billing) {
    for (var bSubKey in this.billing[bKey]) {

      var modeIsEmail = (this.billing[bKey][bSubKey].mode == 'email');
      var emailElementIsMissing = (typeof this.billing[bKey][bSubKey].email == 'undefined');

      if (modeIsEmail && emailElementIsMissing) {
        var newDoc = this;
        delete newDoc._id;
        emit('document', newDoc);
      }
    }
  }
}

var reduceFunction = function(documentKey, badRecord) {
  return badRecord;
}


db.cust.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, { out:"test_reduce"})
```

While this technically works I am annoyed and confused by the structure of the output.  This is what the output looks like:

```
"_id" : "document",
"value" : {
  "billing": {
    "category1": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email",
        "email": {
          "0": "test@what.com" 
        } 
      } 
    },
    "category2": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email",
        "email": {
          "0": "who@cares.net" 
        } 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Why is my resulting structure not exactly the same as the original documents?  What i need is to get rid of the "_id" and "value" elements at the root and return this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("542ec1a91d40cafd58b928b4"),
  "billing": {
    "category1": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email",
        "email": {
          "0": "test@what.com" 
        } 
      } 
    },
    "category2": {
      "0": {
        "mode": "email"
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you considered using `find` with a `$where` query instead since you don't need the reduce part of map-reduce?

Comment: I would have preferred that and did in fact try it but could not come up with a solution.  The problem is that i could not determine how to put a variable key in the where clause.  In the actual data that i am querying there are several random factors such as:  1) there are actually six different possibilities for object keys under the "billing" node.  2) the billing node is not the only one with this structure at this level, there is another one with two different category type nodes under it.  3) there is a variable amount of array elements under each category type node.

Comment: Note: I would have preferred to do a query like the following but this is not possible (i don't think):   db.cust.find({"* . * . * .mode":"email"," * . * . * .email":{ $exists: false }})   where the asterisks are wildcards.